# Attribute table profiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm wondering if there's a way to set up profiles for people as an attribute, where all associated attributes for a person would move with them if that person (as a piece of data) was moved from one polygon's attribute table to another?

In short, I'm using GIS not for geographic analysis but more for the CAD capabilities and use/integration of the attribute data. To create a floorplan, I need to know if I could create a profile for "John Smith" for the attribute table and all associated data for John Smith would be moved from one attribute table to another if the person's office moved.

Comment: Without seeing how your data is structured. An option might be to use "Related Tables" in ArcMap. Basically you can use the person's name as the Join field. If someone moves offices, then the Related Table will "move" with the person's name, if spelt correctly etc.

Comment: @KeaganAllan this seems a good advice to me. You should put it as an answer to the question

Comment: @KeaganAllan approach seems like a simple and elegant solution.  Just one further suggestion to add to it:  Don't use the persons name as the key field (join field), use an ID number field instead.  IDs don't change, but names do (sometimes).  IDs can be managed such that they will be unique, but names can (sometimes) be duplicated.  Etc.

Comment: It might be massive overkill, but this seems to be what Esri's (relatively) new Indoors solution does. (I work for 'em, but know nothing about it, except that it exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use "Related Tables".

This operates similarily to a Table Join, to create a "Related Table".

1. Right-click the layer you want to add the Related Table to, in the options that pop-up, head to Joins & Relates, click Relate
2. Choose the field you want to base the relate off (Office Name)
3. Choose the table you want to use as the source of the data
4. Give the relate a name and select ok.

The tables will be related.

Here is the link to the ESRI Doc:

[Relating the attributes in one table to another](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/relating-the-attributes-in-one-table-to-another.htm)

Here is some more info:

[Accessing related table records](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/accessing-related-records.htm)